# Django get object from QueryDict

Tags: django, post, request

I have a model called barcard, and a form for selecting one of the barcards in the database. My objective is to get an instance of the selected barcard. I have the following code:

models.py

```
class Barcard(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    drinks = models.ManyToManyField(Drink)
    barcardFile = models.FileField(blank=True, upload_to='barcard') 
    mixingFile = models.FileField(blank=True, upload_to='mixing') 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

forms.py

```
class BarcardGenForm(forms.Form):
    barcard = forms.ModelChoiceField(Barcard.objects.all())
```

views.py

```
class BarcardSelect(FormView):
    template_name = 'drinks/home.html'
    form_class = BarcardGenForm
    success_url = 'download/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        return super().form_valid(form)

def barcardGen(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        card = request.POST.get('barcard')
        barcardName = card.name
        card.generateFiles()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('drinks/download/?b='+barcadName)
    return render(request, 'drinks/download.html')
```

When i use get() on the QueryDict, with the key 'barcard' it returns a string, with a number. It seems like the number correspond to the index, that the selected barcard has in the ModelChoiceField. I had hoped that the card variable would contain an instance of a barobject or a name, so i could make a query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get card object by using barcard from the post you should make a query with your `card` variable. `card_obj = Barcard.objects.get(id=card)` and than instead of `card` use that `card_obj`. For example `barcardName = card_obj.name`.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks. I think I have to read a bit about how id works. ;)